# Results get changed by adding one more left join

Tags: mysql

Following are my two queries in which by adding only one more left join result gets messed up. 2nd query result is accurate but in 1st query by adding one more left join output is not right (as you can see i only added one more left join but i didnot put any filteration for that join in where clause) . Kindly let me know how can i fix this? Thanks,

**1st Query:**

```
SELECT Distinct  count(event_id) as event_count from events 
Left Join events on events.event_id = my_events.i_event_id 
Left Join atdees on events.event_id = atdees.fk_event_id

where my_events.v_title != "NULL" and  r_present = 1 and resident_id = '208'  and event_atd > date_sub(curdate(), interval 37 day) group by event_count  order by event_count desc limit 5
```

Result:

```
26  |  12   |  11   |   10
```

**2nd Query:**

```
SELECT Distinct  count(event_id) as event_count from events 
Left Join events on events.event_id = my_events.i_event_id 

where my_events.v_title != "NULL" and  r_present = 1 and resident_id = '208'  and event_atd > date_sub(curdate(), interval 37 day) group by event_count  order by event_count desc limit 5
```

Result:

```
2  |  1   |  1   |   1
```

Comment: Without the data it's hard to see what's going on. Adding joins obviously does later the results, but what's going on in your case is hard to tell without going into details.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question.  If the 2nd query returns correct results, then just use that.  The extra join in the 1st query is returning higher counts because there are more than one match for one or several event_ids.

Comment: Perhaps you are getting confused on how to use DISTINCT for your purposes.  Try using `COUNT(DISTINCT event_id)` instead of `DISTINCT COUNT(event_id)`.  Does that give you what you want?

Comment: @PinnyM actually i have to put filteration for one check its something like if this id in that table is not zero then do this else do this, but with or without that Check, It gives the output i mentioned in the 1st query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the left join does is that it adds extra (duplicate) rows.

If you strip out the `count` and just list the rows, you'll see many duplicate rows.
This is because you're asking for the cross product between `events` and `atdees`; and of course there are many more combinations of events and atdees then there are just events.

Basic logic really.

Change your top query to

```
SELECT count(distinct event_id) as event_count from events 
Left Join events on events.event_id = my_events.i_event_id 
Left Join atdees on events.event_id = atdees.fk_event_id

where my_events.v_title != "NULL" and  r_present = 1 and resident_id = '208'
and event_atd > date_sub(curdate(), interval 37 day) 
group by event_count  
order by event_count desc 
limit 5
```

And you should be getting the same results *(although this is much slower)*

Further note that `left join`s **do not filter**, they add stuff.
If you want to filter you'd use `inner join`s
(*This is a **gross** oversimplification*)

**About `distinct`**
The `distinct` keyword can work inside and outside of an aggregate function.
If you use it inside, it will only count (sum etc) unique values. 
If you use it outside the aggregate function it will only list unique rows.

That is: `distinct` on its own eliminates duplicate rows (it works on all columns in the result set).

`distinct` in a function works as a filter for that function only.

Comment: Kindly let me know one more thing `A Or B AND C` the highlighted clause means if a or b (any one) AND C then do this or it means if A (is true)  or B AND C (is true).

Comment: @softgenic Put parens around the clauses to make it explicit what order you want to the validation to occur in... either `(a or b) and c`, or `a or (b and c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, not `DISTINCT COUNT()`:

```
SELECT count(distinct event_id) as event_count from events
```

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` will count the number of distinct values, instead of the number of rows... when you add your additional `LEFT JOIN`, you are increasing the number of rows, changing the result of `COUNT()`.

Also, you might double-check your `GROUP BY`... it doesn't make sense to be grouping by an aggregate function.